# wp-graphql - can't query acf globalOptions

Tags: wordpress, graphql, advanced-custom-fields, graphiql, wp-graphql

I create a new field in Custom Fields and give it a location, like this:

[image]

After that I activate the *Show In GraphQL* button and set acf name:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to make a query for acf globalOptions in wp-graphql and it gives me an error. Moreover, I can't find globalOptions either in suggestions or in the schema.

GraphiQL-IDE:
[image: playground]

Docs:

[image: schema]

How could I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: without location?

Comment: what do you mean 'without location'? Should I delete or choose something different?

Comment: you used this term

Comment: I used it because of the pic, I mean Rules that define where to show selected acf

Comment: how it (location) is (can be) related to graphql API ?

Comment: 1. Creating acf gives me the possibility to create new fields in acf.
2. Setting rules give me the possibility to show those fields in Global Options and upload real data.
3. Plugin `WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields` gives me the possibility to add acfs to the graphql scheme.
4. If I'm right, after that I could be able to query those fields from graphql IDE.

Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: Options PAGE != global options ? there is no PAGE in API context

Comment: `Advanced Custom Fields PRO` contains Global Options that generate this rule automatically.

Comment: so what is the solution, how can I approach my aim? I just want to query global options in graphql (p.s other acf queries work)

Comment: and this is not related to `/wp-admin/options-general.php` ?  screen and page terms in rule means nothing? ... I don't think it's graphql type related ... probably (didn't read ACL docs about that) you have to use `register_graphql_field` to 'manually' extend graphql `globalOptions` type

Comment: I've already added in `functions.php` this peace of code:
`if (function_exists('acf_add_options_page')) {
    acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title' => __('Global Options'),
        'menu_title' => __('Global Options'),
        'autoload' => true,
    ));
}`
Do you mean this in registering 'manually'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in a file `functions.php`:

it was like:

```
acf_add_options_page(array(
    'page_title' => __('Global Options'),
    'menu_title' => __('Global Options'),
    'autoload' => true,
));
```

But it should be like:

```
acf_add_options_page(array(
    'page_title' => __('Global Options'),
    'menu_title' => __('Global Options'),
    'autoload' => true,
    'show_in_graphql' => true
));
```

I was missing the `'show_in_graphql' => true` key:value pair.

Comment: hmmm, I have to check these options ... key name is taken from titles? is lang/translation related? `graphql_single_name` or `graphql_plural_name` can be used? ... you can accept your own answer

Comment: I can accept my answer after one day. The key name is taken from GraphQL Field name and after that, you are able to make a query like `globalOptions { acfGlobalOptions { //...} }`. What do you mean by a single or plural name, btw?

Comment: single/plural are params for CPT used by wp-graphql plugin, used to define root keys like `post` and `posts` ... in this case it could (if works) be used to rename `globalOptions` key name - define it independently, not related to menu/page [translated] title

Comment: I think it's single because hierarchy is like globalOptions > acfGlobalOptions > [ array of fields defined in acfGlobalOption]. Also in `Rules`, I have only one (selected) option.

Comment: probably ... but ... is it (`'globalOptions'` key name) changeable with `graphql_single_name` param ?

Comment: I think yes, by changing `page_title` and/or `menu_title` key values in `functions.php`

Comment: ... but ... with `graphql_single_name` instead [of possibly translated titles] ?

Comment: I tried both(`single` nad `plural`) but has no affect. `page_title`([see img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fcrX.png)) value changing causes Rule's last select field name's changing

Comment: Thank you too ;) If that helped you please thumbs up my answer, I'll be so grateful